# Reason action hook won't work with update_post_meta from frontend form? Alternative?

Tags: custom-post-types, forms, front-end, post-meta

The code below works when I am inserting a post/using add_post_meta when submitting a form. The page refresh is flawless (see [How can I fix a slow redirect after form submit from frontend (no plugin)?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189210/how-can-i-fix-a-slow-redirect-after-form-submit-from-frontend-no-plugin/189212#189212)). However, I can't seem to get the same effect when using forms that I intend to update the post meta for my custom post type using update_post_meta.

```
function wpd_check_submission(){
    if( isset( $_POST['start'] ) ) {
        // do your post insertion here
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_check_submission' );
```

Could anyone help point me in the right direction? I can't find a clear answer on this. I've tried using the save_post hook, putting the if-isset lines directly after my form, adding the update_post_meta functions directly into the function that is working. I've started reading about do_action methods for updating post meta that have updated_post_meta and update_post_meta--I'm really confused.

Here's an example: the code that works:

```
   function ty_save_post_data() {

    if( isset( $_POST['start'] ) ) { 

        $post = array(
        'post_title' => $_POST[ 'mfname' ],
        'post_status' => 'publish', 
        'post_type' => 'add-members' 
        );  


        $post_id = wp_insert_post($post); 

        add_post_meta($post_id, 'mfname', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'mfname' ] ), true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'mem', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'mem' ] ), true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'mpw', esc_attr( $_POST['mpw'] ), true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'second-nom', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'second-nom' ] ), true );
    } 
    }

add_action( 'init', 'ty_save_post_data' );
```

The code that fails:

```
function ty_save_post_data1() { 
if( isset( $_POST['isecond'] ) ) { 
   update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'second-nom', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['second-nom'] ) );
   update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'second-nom-date', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['second-nom-date'] ) );
   update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'approved', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['approved'] ) );    
}
}

add_action( 'init', 'ty_save_post_data1' );
```

**HERE IS THE UPDATED WORKING VERSION OF THE FAILED CODE EXAMPLE**

```
//hidden field added to form that grabs the post ID
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" />

<?php function ty_save_post_data1() { 
if( isset( $_POST['isecond'] ) ) {

   $post_id1 = $_POST['post_id'];

   update_post_meta( $post_id1, 'second-nom', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['second-nom'] ) );
   update_post_meta( $post_id1, 'second-nom-date', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['second-nom-date'] ) );
   update_post_meta( $post_id1, 'approved', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['approved'] ) );    
}
}

add_action( 'init', 'ty_save_post_data1' );
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context of your code that fails isn't entirely clear, but it's failing because `get_the_ID()` won't return a post ID when run on the `init` hook, because the main query hasn't been executed yet.

If you have a look at the [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), `wp` is the earliest action where you can access the current query's data, if your code is operating on the currently viewed post. If your code is operating on a different post, you'll need to pass that post's ID along with your other form data.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! Solved. See edit. Thank you!